# firestore OnCreate not triggered when creation is done by a sub document or collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I am building a chat app using flutter and firebase and I need to trigger a function whenever two new users starting chatting with each other for the first time (whenever one of them sent the first message) so I can store that information somewhere to show it later to the users as chat history (people who've got in contact with).

So my data tree looks like this : 'rooms/{roomId}/messages/{messageWithRandomId}'

Logically whenever a user sends the first message to another user the room document gets created along with the sub-collection 'messages' containing a single message document with a randomId.
`

I've set up an OnCreate listener on the room's collection and it gets triggered whenever I manually create a new document under 'rooms'.

But it doesn't get triggered when that same document is created by the subcollection.

So my Code looks like this :

```
export const testfunction = functions.firestore.document('rooms/{_someRoom}').onCreate(async (snapshot,context) => {

// the function Core
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It doesn't get triggered when that same document is created by the
>   subcollection.

This is the normal behavior.

As a matter of fact, if you create a document directly under a `messages` collection with the full path `rooms/{roomId}/messages/{messageWithRandomId}`, **no intermediate documents will be created** (i.e. no `roomId` document).

So, when you say:

> the `room` document gets created along with the sub-collection
>   `messages` containing a single message document with a `randomId`

, if you only created the message document with a `randomId`, **there is actually no `room` document created and, consequently, the Cloud Function is not triggered**.

The Firebase console shows in italics the `roomId` room "document" as a kind of "container" (or "placeholder"), in order to "materialize" the hierarchy and to allow you to navigate to the `messageWithRandomId` message document, but the room document doesn't exist in the Firestore database.

---

Let's take a more generic example: Imagine a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one subDoc1 under the subCol1 (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

Actually, **from a technical perspective, they are not at all relating to each other.** They just share a part of their path but nothing else. One side effect of this is that if you delete a document, its sub-collection(s) still exist.

---

This means that you should either:

Create yourself the `roomId` document under the `rooms` collection

OR

trigger your Cloud Function with:

```
export const testfunction = functions.firestore.document('rooms/{_someRoom}/messages/{_someMessage}').onCreate(async (snapshot,context) => {
  //.....   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the clear explanation :)